# Compilation error: error: object scalatest is not a member of package.org, am NOT using sbt

Tags: scala, scalatest

I've been programming in Scala for about a week, but not with sbt - I downloaded the 'scala binaries for windows' (using Windows 10) and have just been writing scripts using a text editor, and compiling and executing via the command line, e.g.

```
  /** Calculate factorial of n
    * Pre: n >= 0
    * Post: returns n! */
  def fact(n: Int) : BigInt = {
    require(n>=0)
    if(n==0) 1 else fact(n-1)*n
  }

  // Main method
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = { 
    print("Please input a number: ")
    val n = scala.io.StdIn.readInt()
    if(n>=0){
      val f = fact(n)
      println("The factorial of "+n+" is "+f)
    }
    else println("Sorry, negative numbers aren't allowed")
  }
}
```

and then:

[image: Compiling with scalac and executing via the command line]

So far, so good. Enter: ScalaTest.

```
import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite

import Factorial.fact

class FactTest extends AnyFunSuite {
   test("0! is 1"){ assert(fact(0) === 1) }
   test("5! is 120") { assert(fact(5) === 120) }
   test("3! is 5") {assert(fact(3) === 5) } //Want to see what happens when the test isn't passed
}
```

But this will not compile.

[image: Attempting to compile gives the object scalatest is not a member of package.org error]

I'm running scala 2.13.4, so the versions all match up (I believe?)

My best guess at what's going on is I don't think scalac is actually finding/using the ScalaTest file, but I have no clue why.

Any help?

EDIT: Have added the funsuite scalatest jar, still not working...

[image: Attempted compiling now also using funsuite jar]

Comment: Because `scalac` doesn't have any way to find that file because such file doesn't exists in your system, and even if it does you are not managing the classpath. Doing that manually would be a nightmare, that is why nobody does that manually and instead we use build tools like **sbt** to define the dependencies of our projects.

Comment: But the file does exist in my system - they're all there, which you can see when I ran dir. And I am managing the classpath - that's the -cp option when I run scalac, isn't it?

Comment: It should, no idea why it doesn't work, as I said nobody does this by hand. Anyways try without passing anything, AFAIK the current folder is always in the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be that I was attempting to use seperate versions of Scalatic and Scalatest, despite that they were integrated recently.

Downloading and using as the classpath scalatest-app_2.13-3.2.2.jar fixed everything.

Answer (score 2):

The main ScalaTest JAR doesn't include `AnyFunSuite`. You'll also need the `scalatest-funsuite_2.13-3.2.3.jar`. And the main ScalaTest JAR doesn't only depend on the scalactic JAR; it also depends on `scalatest-core_2.13-3.2.3.jar`, so you'll need that on your classpath as well.

Perhaps you need some other JARs as well -- I didn't look. The point of my answer isn't to say "here are the specific JARs you need in this specific case". The point of my answer is to educate you -- to say "in general, libraries have transitive dependencies, and they may go any number of levels deep", and if you don't take that into account when assembling a classpath, failure is predictable.

You can look at the POMs for these JARs to find out what their dependencies are, recursively. A build tool would do that for you automatically and assemble an appropriate classpath for you, without you needing to go through this trouble.

If you are resistant to using a full build tool but are open to using a smaller tool that only handles downloading dependency trees and assembling a classpath for you, consider using [Coursier](https://get-coursier.io).

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about this. But then again, why does it says _"object `scalatest` is not a member of `org`"_?

Comment: This didn't end up working - any other suggestions?